# Invoking Void Method to print an integer as text

Tags: java, methods, invoke, void

I'm confused on what to put in the parameter of the `oneDigit` method and what to put in the main method where I invoke the `oneDigit method` in order to print out the four digit integer 4321 in words (Four Three Two One). Any help would be much appreciated!

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class ToEnglish {

   public static void oneDigit(int n1, int n2, int n3, int n4){

   }//end oneDigit

    public static void main(String[] args) {

      int number;
      int n1;
      int n2;
      int n3;
      int n4;
      String input;

      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                                   "Welcome to the ToEnglish program by Josh Higgins!",
                                   "ToEnglish",
                                   JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
      input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                                               "Please enter a four-digit integer",
                                               "ToEnglish",
                                               JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
      number = Integer.parseInt(input);

      //breaking integer up into 4 digits
      n1 = number / 1000;
      int n1Remainder = number % 1000;
      n2 = n1Remainder / 100;
      int n2Remainder = number % 100;
      n3 = n2Remainder / 10;
      int n3Remainder = number % 10;
      n4 = number % 10;

      if
      (number < 0000 || number > 9999) { 
         System.out.println("Invalid input");
      }
      else {
      n1 = number / 1000;
      n1Remainder = number % 1000;
      n2 = n1Remainder / 100;
      n2Remainder = number % 100;
      n3 = n2Remainder / 10;
      n3Remainder = number % 10;
      n4 = number % 10;
      }

      if ((number > 0000) && (number < 9999)) {
      System.out.println(n1 + " " + n2 + " " + n3 + " " + n4 + " ");
      }
      else {
      System.out.println("Invalid input");
      }

      //invoking oneDigit Method in order to print the four digit integer in text
      oneDigit(n1);
      oneDigit(n2);
      oneDigit(n3);
      oneDigit(n4);

 System.out.println("All done for now!");
      System.exit(0);

   }//end of the main method

}//end of the class
```

---

**@Vishal, this is my improved code, but when I run it, I only get 4 3 2 1, not the text. Any suggestions?**

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class ToEnglish {

   public void oneDigit(int digit){

   }//end oneDigit

    public static void main(String[] args) {

      int digit=0;
      int number;
      int n1;
      int n2;
      int n3;
      int n4;
      String input;

      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                                   "Welcome to the ToEnglish program by Josh Higgins!",
                                   "ToEnglish",
                                   JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
      input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                                               "Please enter a four-digit integer",
                                               "ToEnglish",
                                               JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
      number = Integer.parseInt(input);

      //breaking integer up into 4 digits
      n1 = number / 1000;
      int n1Remainder = number % 1000;
      n2 = n1Remainder / 100;
      int n2Remainder = number % 100;
      n3 = n2Remainder / 10;
      int n3Remainder = number % 10;
      n4 = number % 10;

      if
      (number < 0000 || number > 9999) { 
         System.out.println("Invalid input");
      }
      else {
      n1 = number / 1000;
      n1Remainder = number % 1000;
      n2 = n1Remainder / 100;
      n2Remainder = number % 100;
      n3 = n2Remainder / 10;
      n3Remainder = number % 10;
      n4 = number % 10;
      }

      if ((number > 0000) && (number < 9999)) {
      System.out.println(n1 + " " + n2 + " " + n3 + " " + n4 + " ");
      }
      else {
      System.out.println("Invalid input");
      }

      switch (digit) {
         case 1 : System.out.print("One");
         break;
         case 2 : System.out.print("Two");
         break;
         case 3 : System.out.print("Three");
         break;
         case 4 : System.out.print("Four");
         break;
         case 5 : System.out.print("Five");
         break;
         case 6 : System.out.print("Six");
         break;
         case 7 : System.out.print("Seven");
         break;
         case 8 : System.out.print("Eight");
         break;
         case 9 : System.out.print("Nine");
         break;
       }

 System.out.println("All done for now!");
      System.exit(0);

   }//end of the main method

}//end of the class
```

Comment: do some research how to use methods in java

Answer (score 0):

According to your method prototype, the oneDigit method accepts four integers and you have called the method with only one integer.
You could write the method with one parameter. Inside the method use a switch case with the parameter to print the number in words.

For example:
This code should be written inside the oneDigit method

```
public static void oneDigit(int digit) {
    switch(digit) {
        case 1 : System.out.print("One");
                 break;
        //Other cases followed
}
```

You could follow this with all the digits.

Or you could write an if-else if blocks to check which integer is passed to the method and print the digit in words in that block.

EDIT : The code block

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
public static String oneDigit(int digit){
  switch(digit){
    case 0:
    return "zero";
    case 1:
    return "one";
    //add missing cases
    default:
    return "not in range"; //you can throw an exception here if you prefer
  }
}
```